# CommonMark doesn't generate correct HTML markup

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown

I have tried editing this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887975/1839439

This is what I see in the preview:

> [image]

This is what I get after saving:

> [image]

This is the markdown used:

````
You can try this if it helps you 

1)
    ```
    $response['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
    $response['status'] = 'ok';
    $response['msg'] = "successfully";
    //output data jsone
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit; // add exit so it stops execution and you can see the data in response
    ```
 

2) decode your JSON response 

        var data = JSON.parse(response);
    
        console.log(data.status)
````

The problem is that the code in the numbered list is inlined instead of block code.

Comment: Relevant example in the CommonMark spec: https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#example-248

Comment: Side note: you really should remove/reword "You can try this if it helps you" - editing posts that don't actually provide answer to the question does not look like best use of one's time...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree maybe I should reword that first sentence, but this is still an answer. It could use a better explanation though, which would be a valid reason to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, CommonMark doesn't allow a list line to be empty, and the first line of list item one is in your code.

This doesn't explain the different behavior of the preview, though, which is likely a bug, and I also can't explain the rendering as inline code.

Two workarounds:

1. Don't leave it empty, but list the code directly on the first line

   ````
   1)  ```
       $response['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
       $response['status'] = 'ok';
       $response['msg'] = "successfully";
       //output data jsone
       echo json_encode($response);
       exit; // add exit so it stops execution and you can see the data in response
       ```
   ````
2. Throw a `&nbsp;` non-breaking space on the first line to format the code below the `1.`

   ````
   1)  &nbsp;
       ```
       $response['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
       $response['status'] = 'ok';
       $response['msg'] = "successfully";
       //output data jsone
       echo json_encode($response);
       exit; // add exit so it stops execution and you can see the data in response
       ```
   ````